# Select/deselect ALL folders for offline use in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

I have an e-mail account in Thunderbird with more than 100 IMAP-folders.

**Is there an easy way to select or deselect all these folders for offline use?**

Currently I have to manually click the checkbox in front of every folder if I want to download all of them or just one or two. I would like an option to select/deselect all as well as on a folder hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the easiest was to, when setting up the new account go into File ≫ Offline ≫ Offline Settings ≫ <NEW_ACCOUNT>  and then uncheck the box with the text "Keep messages in all folders for this account on this computer" next to it (and then using the "Advanced" button to select ONLY those folders I wanted to be kept available for offline use (pretty much just "Inbox").

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer helped me to solve the described issue and should thus be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

In "Account Settings" you can untick "Keep messages in all folders for this account on this computer".  Then click "Advanced" to select the ones you do want to synchronise:

[image: Thunderbird screenshot]